# Javascript manipulation of display:none doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a JS price calculator and I'm stuck on one part, where I do not find a solution for a couple of hours. I will appreciate your help.

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. Displaying part, where there are 3 product types (`<input type="radio"`). Clicking to one of them should appear with own LightBox and also hiding other parts of the `<input>` form.

```
<div>
    <h2>Basic Price</h2>
    <div id="singleSpotLB" style="display:block;">
        <?php include "/Templates/singleSpotLightBox.php"?>
    </div>
    <div id="multiSpotLB" style="display: none;">
        <?php include "/Templates/multiSpotLightBox.php"?>
    </div>
    <div id="photoSilkLB" style="display: none;">
        <?php include "/Templates/photoSilk.php"?>
    </div>

    <label for="type">Transfer Type</label><br>
    <div>
        <label for="sSpot">
            <input type="radio" name="type" id="sSpot" onclick="invisibleColors()"> SingleSpot
        </label>
        <label for="mSpot">
            <input type="radio" name="type"id="mSpot" onclick="invisibleColors()"> MultiSpot
        </label>
        <label for="pSilk">
            <input type="radio" name="type"id="pSilk" onclick="invisibleColors()"> PhotoSilk
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

2. Javascript part for hiding (by `style.display = "none";`) the divs which do not belong to the chosen product:

```
function invisibleColors() {
    let sSpot = document.getElementsByName("type");
    let singleSpotLB = document.getElementById("singleSpotLB");
    let multiSpotLB = document.getElementById("multiSpotLB");
    let photoSilkLB = document.getElementById("photoSilkLB");

    if (sSpot[0].checked) {
        document.getElementById('colorDiv').style.display = "none";
        singleSpotLB.style.display = "block";
        multiSpotLB.style.display = "none";
        photoSilkLB.style.display = "none";
    } else if (sSpot[1].checked) {
        document.getElementById('colorDiv').style.display = "block";
        singleSpotLB.style.display = "none";
        multiSpotLB.style.display = "block";
        photoSilkLB.style.display = "none";
    } else if (sSpot[2].checked) {
        document.getElementById('colorDiv').style.display = "none";
        singleSpotLB.style.display = "none";
        multiSpotLB.style.display = "none";
        photoSilkLB.style.display = "block";

    }
}
```

**The problem:
When I'm testing the code it works well at the beginning but after a couple of clicks the `label` texts change properly, but the images just don't load.

Thanks, and I hope someone could help.

P.S Content of the PHP files from where the LighBox is loaded:

```
<label for="type">SingleSpot</label>
    <div class="masonry-thumbs grid-container grid-3 clearfix">
        <a class="grid-item" href="http://ttransferhall.de/images/portfolio/4/1.jpg" data-lightbox="image">
            <div class="grid-inner">
                <img src="http://ttransferhall.de/images/portfolio/4/1.jpg" alt="Single Image">
                <div class="bg-overlay">
                    <div class="bg-overlay-content dark">
                        <i class="icon-line-plus h4 mb-0" data-hover-animate="fadeIn"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bg-overlay-bg dark" data-hover-animate="fadeIn"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>

    </div>
```

Here is a video of the [result](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcGNjPyck-k&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Can you create a minimal snippet?

Comment: The bit you are talking about: "but the images just don't load", seems to be the one bit you haven't included in the question. Try replacing those PHP includes with some plain text and see if it works, that will tell you whether the problem is in this code or whatever the PHP is including.

Comment: @DBS sorry, I should have made it. In the PHP file, there is only a pure HTML for the divs with an image. There is also a ```<h3>``` with the name of the product, and it changes properly.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Sorry, I tried to trim the unnecessary parts

Comment: No i mean if you can create a snippet without php just css and html and see result

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I tried that too. I placed the content of the php files directly into the HTML and unfortunately the result is the same. The label is loading well and the text changes, but the images look buggy and sometimes load sometimes don’t. I was wondering if I miss something in the JS array for the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is an ajax process loaded from the template, which conflicts with the plain JS script. Thank you all for your opinions and help.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexandar Dimov Your code in Html is owner than the code in javascript. add your style in other file CSS and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I tried to not adding `style="display: none;"` at all, and control the display property in the JS file. It didn't work. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I think what you are trying to say is that the inline style has a higher priority than the JS styles, but that isn't accurate, JS sets styles inline, so it would replace what was there originally.